# How to extract integers from array of strings in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Given an array of the form

```
char* timePeriod= {"6AM#8AM","11AM#1PM","7AM#3PM","7AM#10AM","10AM#12PM"};
```

how can I extract the start and end time in integer arrays of following form:

```
start_time={6,11,7,7,10}
end_time={8,1,3,10,12}
```

Comment: Uh-oh, date parseing detected! Use a date-parsing library, never do it yourself! http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "sscanf" to do so. And don't forget to mark it as useful :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int a,b,i;
    int start_time[5], end_time[5];

    char *t[5] = {"6AM#8AM","11AM#1PM","7AM#3PM","7AM#10AM","10AM#12PM"};
    char *(*ptr)[5] = &t;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        sscanf((*ptr)[i], "%d%*[AP]M#%d%*[AP]M", &a, &b);
        start_time[i]=a;
        end_time[i]=b;
    }
    printf("Starting time : ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",start_time[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEnding time : ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",end_time[i]);
    }  
    return 0;
}
OUTPUT:
Starting time : 6 11 7 7 10 
Ending time : 8 1 3 10 12
```

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple way would be to use `strtok` to split the string on the #, then use `atoi` on each piece. It will stop once it sees a non-numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf` is capable of doing this, although I don't think it's a very good way. look at [here](http://docs.roxen.com/pike/7.0/tutorial/strings/sscanf.xml) for details

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  const char* t = "6PM#8AM";
  int a, b;
  sscanf(t, "%d%*[AP]M#%d%*[AP]M", &a, &b);
  printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

or you can `regex` in C++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  string t("6PM#8AM");
  smatch match;
  regex re("([[:digit:]])+[AP]M#([[:digit:]])+[AP]M");
  if (regex_match(t, match, re)) {
    cout << match[1].str() << " " << match[2].str() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: the following solution makes a few very specific assumptions about your dataset (if these are not the case, you may prefer using a regex).

1. The string will always start with integers
2. The endtimes will always either be in the 4th or 5th index of your string
3. Zero is not a valid time

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string timePeriod[5] = {"6AM#8AM","11AM#1PM","7AM#3PM","7AM#10AM","10AM#12PM"};
    int   startTimes[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
    int     endTimes[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

        std::string s = timePeriod[i];
        startTimes[i] = atoi(s.c_str());             // Convert first number to integer
        endTimes[i]   = atoi(s.substr(4).c_str());   // Convert 2nd numbers to integer
        if(endTimes[i] == 0)                         // If zero
            endTimes[i] = atoi(s.substr(5).c_str()); // Get the 5th index instead

        std::cout << "Start: " << startTimes[i] << "\t End: " << endTimes[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The lack of leading zeros makes it a bit trickier, but ultimately - it can be quickly solved using substrings (assuming also you don't mind changing the char* into a std::string).